# XOR String Encryption/Decryption

Tags: c++, encryption

I have made programs that utilize XOR encryption of data before and fully understand it, but how can I implement this into a program so the string literals are encrypted? For instance, I do not want to use:

```
string name = "My name is Matt";
```

This would cause "My name is Matt" to be located in the executable. I am guessing I would have to encrypt the literal with a separate program, but my real question is how do I store the encrypted string in the executable (preferably not in a separate file)?

Again, I fully understand how to decrypt the strings and how it works, I just need to know how to transport the encrypted strings in the compiled result.

Thank you for your time, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: By "XOR Encryption" you really mean that you are "making it slightly difficult to extract information using an XOR transformation," right?  Because a so-called "XOR encryption" algorithm really offers no security.

Comment: XOR encryption is 100% reliable with one-time padding...

Comment: Given his 'full understanding' of XOR encryption, I'm surprised it matters where or how the information is stored at all. :P Just keep it in an ASCII text file in the directory with the program, and insert a letter `Z` every other letter. :P

Comment: @James: The security offered by an XOR encryption algorithm can be quite reasonable (though not as good as conventional encryption, of course), depending on the algorithm used (for example, a scheme involving the encrypting of each character with the previous character, and the first character with a secret key, is harder to figure out than a scheme encrypting each character only with a secret key).

Comment: @Jason Goemaat : He is not using One-time padding. Even the Russians back in the cold war who were supposedly using OTP were not actually using OTP, and it was quickly broken. OTP is almost impossible to use correctly due to the sheer volume of key data required.

Comment: @Cameron : I guess our ideas of "quite reasonable" would differ considerably. I don't consider anything that an average adult can decypher in a couple hours with paper and pen to be 'reasonable'.

Comment: @James McNellis: @ Andrew Barber: Given a good key XOR encryption is pretty much unbreakable in reasonable time (reasonable being years). I just paste chapter one of my favorite book as the key (true a bad key; but you as a person will never be able to decode it). The only trouble with XOR encryption is that it is hard to securely transfer the key to a second party which is not relevant here.

Comment: Feel free to decode this: "x04x05x03x1bx45x13x28x08x4fx35x00x1c" To even make it easy I used a 48 bit key. So the first and second half of the target are being encrypted by the same key.

Comment: @Martin: is the third character one of the following: 'l', 'b', space, comma?

Comment: @Martin: oops, better throw in tuxyz and 45689 as possibilities. Anyway, in your hypothetical example I'm pretty sure that a professional cryptanalyst can discover fairly easily that your cyphertext is the XOR of two English texts. Identifying the key is easy if it happens to be in an available corpus (as your favourite book no doubt is if I, as a person, work for GCHQ), somewhat harder otherwise. But I personally don't work for GCHQ. If James or Andrew does, I don't think your assertion is correct - a chapter from a book isn't a bad key, it's a terrible key.

Comment: Generally, XORs not too bad if you're just trying to *frustrate* casual "strings x | less" snooping or a cracker searching for phrases ala "license expired", will stop 90% who're lazy.  @Cameron: "encrypting of each character with the previous, and the first with a secret key" is succeptible to cracking based on common sequences (e.g. " the ").  A combination of previous character and key is better than either alone.  @Andrew: re OTP and "sheer volume" - why assume the volume's "sheer"? - can generate a few kb of OTP easily enough, but terrabytes may be a pain.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, but would it be worth the couple hours? If it's not worth the trouble it takes to decode it, then I would consider the encryption "reasonable" :-)

Comment: @Tony: I'm sure my example is completely crackable, but I fail to see how straightforward frequency analysis could be used against it, since every occurrence of, e.g. "the" would be encrypted differently depending on the characters that came before them (which would be encrypted differently depending on the characters that came before those, etc., all the way back to the first character, which was XORed with the secret key).

Comment: @Martin:  In your example, there is a 2:1 ratio between the text length and the key length.  That kind of ratio is not viable for real-world security and for a simple XOR, the higher the ratio, the easier it is to crack.  XOR is sufficient, as @Tony suggests, if you merely want to make it difficult to get at the information.  It is not at all sufficient for just about any real-world encryption scenario.

Comment: @Matt: FWIW - might be a way to encode the strings in place - maybe something like `const s[] = OBFUSCATE<'h', 'i', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'>::value;` if that's of any use.  Variadic macros may allow another approach with similarly ugly notation.  At least you wouldn't have to run an external program and cut-paste stuff in.  But, I won't bother trying to implement it unless you're interested.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: @James McNellis: Yes: this is not industrial strength encryption (if a large organization (or talented encryption specialist) wanted to get the information they could) but it is way beyond your average individual/developer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036134/encrypting-password-in-compiled-c-or-c-code/3037376#3037376

Comment: @Martin: Bruce Schneier often derides crypto "that you could use against your kid sister", which I never considered a good measure, since my kid sister has a Master's degree in maths and studied cryptography as part of that... Security is too surprising to start with something barely good enough, unless there are unusual constraints that prevent you just throwing "way too good" crypto at it in the first place. It's no easier to distribute a "one" time pad that you're actually going to abuse and weaken by multiple use, than it is to distribute a key for a more robust symmetric cipher.

Comment: I think that perhaps the word 'encryption' in this question should simply be replaced with 'encoding'. Good quality encryption algorithms are freely available and easy to implement. 'Rolling your own' encryption mechanism generally takes more time and effort, and you end up with something weak. If what you are looking for is quick and easy obfuscation, then fine; do that. Run it through a couple simple encoding mechanisms. But *don't call it encryption if that's not what you actually want*.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: @Andrew Barber: yet your sister still is not going to be able to decode my message above. The only way that will be cracked is by brute force (and I think even that is unlikely as there is not enough text). Yes this is encryption. Its just stream encryption mechanism the weakest form of encryption. But it is **fine given a good key**. It can not be used to transfer messages between people as securely transferring the key is a problem. **NEVER** try and implement one of the big boy encryption mechanisms you will get it **WRONG**. ReUse somebody else s implementation.

Comment: @Martin: certainly a twelve byte message isn't going to be decrypted with high confidence, since for all we know, your message doesn't really make sense, and is in fact "AAbAAAYL.ylP", the first possibility I get assuming an alphabet of `A-Za-z0-9 ,.`. Of course if my few lines of Python have a bug, and actually "hello, world" is a possible message, then I'd guess it was that and we'd be done. So in a sense your encryption has relied as much on having a good *message* as having a good *key*. Of course with OTP the two are equivalent anyway.

Comment: ... oh, and you say your example has to be cracked by "brute force", but not by brute force in the usual meaning (trying 2^48 keys and picking the most plausible-looking result). In fact I would start by assuming that the text contains at least one English word. If it doesn't, my attempt fails. Then, given a list of about 50k English worlds, I try each in all possible positions and see whether (a) it is possible, and if so (b) the parts of the key predicted by it produce any English elsewhere. That's a pretty small effort, and with a bit of luck produces a plausible suggestion.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The text is English. Don;t assume the same of the key. Now if you do brute force on that at 1,000,000 keys a second. That should hold for 8 years (if you scan the whole key base). If it is somewhere in the middle it should take you about 4 years. 2^48/1000000/60/60/24/365 = 8.9 Now a cryptologist would be able to do extra stuff and probably narrow the actual key space down to 2^36 keys which at 1,000,000 a second would be less than a day.

Comment: @Martin: I don't need to assume anything about the key other than that you used it twice (which you kindly told me). So I don't care what the key is, it can be randomly generated. I wouldn't scan the keyspace because I know that `0x04 ^ 0x28` is equal to the XOR of the first and seventh bytes of your (English) message. Re-using an XOR keystream means that in effect you are using the second half of your message as an XOR key for the first half, and I can attack it on that basis. Still, as you say, 12 bytes is an awful short message to be confident of an apparent crib.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Now I deliberately made the key weak to make it do-able for this example. But now imagine I pasted a key of 1024 bits (That's only a password of 128 characters Call it 150 since we don't use all the bits.) At this point is beyond the ability of the home user to decrypt. Though well within the ability of a big company or the government (because it is a weak method and easy to find commonalities when the key is repeated).

Comment: ... just checked, and to be specific the assumption that your alphabet is `A-Za-z0-9 ,.` cuts the keyspace down to slightly under 2^31 possibilities. To be fair, that's an optimistically short alphabet, I should probably allow more punctuation. That's before I make any further assumption that the message consists of English words. I'm hardly a "cryptologist" though, to do this tiny amount of analysis.

Comment: "At this point is beyond the ability of the home user to decrypt." - that depends how many times you re-use the key. The more times you re-use it, the more information you provide about the key (i.e. the more bytes there are that you assert "this byte is the result of XORing the key byte with an English character"), and the more the space is cut. If you only use the key once, then it's as secure as the method used to generate it.

Comment: This thread got way more complex than I intended. My software will not be analyzed by cryptologists (hopefully) and the intended users will probably not understand how to use brute force to check all of the strings.

Answer (score 3):

Step one: write a program that encrypts your string then prints them out as hex numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    std::string const  value = argv[1];
    std::string const  key   = argv[2];

    std::cout << "string " << argv[3] << " (\"";
    for(std::size_t loop = 0; loop < value.size(); ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << "\\x"
                  << std::hex
                  << std::setw(2)
                  << std::setfill('0')
                  << static_cast<unsigned int>(value[loop] ^ key[loop % key.size()]);
    }
    std::cout << "\"," << value.size() << ");\n";
}
```

Step 2:  Run the application for each literal. It should output code that you can past into your application.

```
> ./a.exe Martin York Cool
string Cool ("\x14\x0e\x00\x1f\x30\x01",6);
```

Note: As the string may now contain the nul character you can't use the normal string constructor that takes a C-String. You need to use the constructor that takes a char* and a length.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're stripping symbols, you should be able to get away with doing something like:

```
static const char *kMyNameIsMatt = "arosietnarsoitne";  // Where that mess is the XOR-obfuscated string.
string name = kMyNameIsMatt;
std::cout << XORUnobfuscate(name) << std::endl;
```

If you are not stripping symbols, then you can obfuscate the symbols, as well, using something like:

```
#define kMyNameIsMatt ABC123XYZZY
```

Comment: Wow, it is that simple. For some reason I was thinking the encrypted characters I would have to paste in would have some encoding problem since they could be out of the normal ASCII range, but all I had to do was use #define.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a bitwise xor, then your "string" will probably contain a whole lot of unprintable characters, and so you can't define it via `String str = "[something]"`. Your best bet is to represent it as an array of integers representing each char. Then to get your string back, just XOR the various chars, and append them all together to form your unencrypted string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ascii, use hexadecimal character notation...

```
void formatString(char *buffer, char *input) {
    char *pos = buffer;
    while (*input != '\0') {
        sprintf(pos, "\\x%02x", (int)*input);
        input++;
        pos += 4;
    }
}

void main() {
    char buffer[100]; // 4 chars for every char in the input
    char *original = "ABCD";
    int size = formatString(buffer, original);
}
```

This should give you a resulting string like "\x41\x42\x43\x44" that you can put in your program.    Unfortunately when you XOR some of the resulting bytes might be null.  If you end up with "\x57\x00\x68\xf7" in your program then the string will only report as one character long since the null will terminate it, so you need to store the size of the string separately.  This could be handled by Base64 encoding the encrypted string.  Otherwise if you only use ASCII 0-127, you could set bit 7 on each character and end it with a null.  If your XOR values were 0x55, 0x42, 0x55, 0x55 that would convert "ABCD" to 0x14, 0x00, 0x16, 0x11, by setting bit 7 you would get 0x94, 0x80, 0x96, 0x91:

```
void main() {
    char encryptedString = "\x94\x80\x96\x91";
    char buffer[100];
    decryptString(buffer, encryptedString);
    printf("Original: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Where decryptString does the XOR then strips bit 7 by anding with 0x7f.

There's lots of free code out there for Base64 though, so I would just Base64 encode the resulting bytes after XOR, then Base64 decode the string before XORing back to the original.