# How to convert AES_encrypt in counter mode to EVP interfaces?

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes, encryption-symmetric

I'm in the process of coding some stuff around common-encryption which require AES Ctr 128. So I'm digging a bit with crypto stuff.

Currently I test a code (find here) which work (encrypt/decrypt a file):

```c
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


struct ctr_state {
  unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned int num;
  unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
};

void print_hex(unsigned char *c) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%02X.", c[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}


void init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[16]) {
  state->num = 0;
  memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);
  memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);
  memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
}

void fencrypt(char* read, char* write, const unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;
  AES_KEY key;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  struct ctr_state state;


  RAND_bytes(iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

  print_hex(iv);
  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");


  AES_set_encrypt_key(enc_key, 128, &key);

  init_ctr(&state, iv);

  fwrite(state.ivec, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, writeFile);

  print_hex(state.ivec);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    print_hex(state.ivec);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

void fdecrypt(char* read, char* write, const unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;
  AES_KEY key;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  struct ctr_state state;

  readFile=fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile=fopen(write,"wb");

  fread(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

  AES_set_encrypt_key(enc_key, 128, &key);

  init_ctr(&state, iv);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    print_hex(state.ivec);
    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
            break;
    }
  }
  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char* secret = "supersecret";

 fencrypt("encme.txt", "enced.enc", (const unsigned char*)secret);
 fdecrypt("enced.enc", "unenced.txt", (const unsigned char*)secret);
}
```

This work well. But It seems that the standard is to to use EVP functions now with openssl. So I try to adapt my code but something is clearly wrong with my implementations. I don't understand on how properly update/increment the IV vector.

Here my new code with EVP (work but not increment/counter):

```c
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct ctr_state {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX* cipher;
  int num;
};

void print_hex(unsigned char *c) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%02X.", c[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, unsigned char iv[16], unsigned char* key) {
    state->num = 0;
    state->cipher = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(state->cipher, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
}

void fencrypt(char* read, char* write, unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  struct ctr_state state;

  RAND_bytes(iv, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

  fwrite(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, writeFile);
  init_ctr(&state, iv, enc_key);
  print_hex(iv);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(state.cipher, outdata, &state.num, indata, bytes_read);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(state.cipher, outdata, &state.num, indata, bytes_read);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

void fdecrypt(char* read, char* write, unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];

  struct ctr_state state;

  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

  fread(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);
  init_ctr(&state, iv, enc_key);

  print_hex(iv);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

    EVP_EncryptUpdate(state.cipher, outdata, &state.num, indata, bytes_read);
    printf("Pass %d ",state.num);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 char* secret = "supersecret";

 fencrypt("encme.txt", "enced.enc", (unsigned char*)secret);
 fdecrypt("enced.enc", "unenced.txt", (unsigned char*)secret);
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Also see [AES-256 using CTR mode](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/AES-256-using-CTR-mode-td43143.html) on the OpenSSL mailing list. Here's from the message: *"The EVP API is documented here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html. There is some example code there too. It doesn't use AES or CTR, but the principle is the same. Just replace EVP_bf_cbc() with EVP_aes_256_ctr(), and ensure you use an appropriately sized key and IV."*

Comment: Here's a couple of Stack Overflow question/answers: [Is it possible to use AES CTR mode encryption using the EVP API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3783311/608639) and [AES CTR 256 Encryption Mode of operation on OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3141860/608639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I got it.

I will copy here my two program example:

AES_CTR_128 (without EVP) :

```c
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ctr_state {
  unsigned int num;
  unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
};

void init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, const unsigned char iv[16]) {
  state->num = 0;
  memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);
  memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);
  memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
}

void fencrypt(char* read, char* write, const unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;
  AES_KEY key;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  struct ctr_state state;
  unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";

  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

  fwrite(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, writeFile);

  AES_set_encrypt_key(enc_key, 128, &key);
  init_ctr(&state, iv);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

    AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

void fdecrypt(char* read, char* write, const unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;
  AES_KEY key;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  struct ctr_state state;

  readFile=fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile=fopen(write,"wb");

  fread(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

  AES_set_encrypt_key(enc_key, 128, &key);
  init_ctr(&state, iv);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);
    AES_ctr128_encrypt(indata, outdata, bytes_read, &key, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 unsigned char *secret = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";

 fencrypt("encme.txt", "enced.enc", secret);
 fdecrypt("enced.enc", "unenced.txt", secret);
}
```

Everything classic as in another example. 
The IV(or nonce) is constant to make the debugging easier (don't do that).

And below my code with EVP:

```c
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct ctr_state {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX* cipher;
  unsigned int num;
  unsigned char ivec[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char ecount[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
};

static void AES_ctr128_inc(unsigned char *counter) {
  unsigned char* cur_pos;

  for (cur_pos = counter + 15; cur_pos >= counter; cur_pos--) {
    (*cur_pos)++;
    if (*cur_pos != 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

void AES_ctr128_EVPencrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX* cipher, const unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out,
  const unsigned long length,
  unsigned char counter[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
  unsigned char ecount_buf[AES_BLOCK_SIZE],
  unsigned int *num) {

  int nb;
  unsigned int n;
  unsigned long l=length;

  n = *num;

  while (l--) {
    if (n == 0) {
      EVP_EncryptUpdate(cipher, ecount_buf, &nb, counter, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
      AES_ctr128_inc(counter);
    }
    *(out++) = *(in++) ^ ecount_buf[n];
    n = (n+1) % AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
  }

  *num=n;
}

void init_ctr(struct ctr_state *state, unsigned char iv[16], unsigned char* key) {
  state->num = 0;
  memset(state->ecount, 0, 16);
  memset(state->ivec + 8, 0, 8);
  memcpy(state->ivec, iv, 8);
  state->cipher = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(state->cipher, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL);
}

void fencrypt(char* read, char* write, unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  struct ctr_state state;
  unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";

  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

  fwrite(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, writeFile);

  init_ctr(&state, iv, enc_key);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

    AES_ctr128_EVPencrypt(state.cipher, indata, outdata, bytes_read, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

void fdecrypt(char* read, char* write, unsigned char* enc_key) {

  FILE *readFile;
  FILE *writeFile;

  int bytes_read;
  unsigned char indata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char outdata[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
  struct ctr_state state;

  readFile = fopen(read,"rb");
  writeFile = fopen(write,"wb");

  fread(iv, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

  init_ctr(&state, iv, enc_key);

  while(1) {
    bytes_read = fread(indata, 1, AES_BLOCK_SIZE, readFile);

    AES_ctr128_EVPencrypt(state.cipher, indata, outdata, bytes_read, state.ivec, state.ecount, &state.num);

    fwrite(outdata, 1, bytes_read, writeFile);
    if (bytes_read < AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(writeFile);
  fclose(readFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 unsigned char *secret = (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345";

 fencrypt("encme.txt", "enced.enc", (unsigned char*)secret);
 fdecrypt("enced.enc", "unenced.txt", secret);
}
```

So I basically copy the AES_ctr_encrypt function to use EVP, and adapt it.

It work for me, as I can use both implementation to encrypt/decrypt the same program.

Comments are welcome.
Questions remain that what do the aes_ctr_128 in EVP ? and how to use it?
I think I have reinvented the wheel.

Comment: Nicely done -- I tested both code snippets to work -- however I've noticed an important omission: at the end of BOTH fencrypt() and fdecrypt() you also need to call "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(state.cipher);" so that the structures allocated by "EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();" are properly freed after all encryption/decryption is done... -- also one thing I found out the hard way is that every single time EVP_EncryptUpdate() is to be called one must explicitly call EVP_EncryptInit_ex() with the proper context pointer and ALL NULL parameters except for the key -- otherwise EVP_EncryptUpdate() crashes...

Answer (score 1):

In {EVP_aes_N_ctr()} the counter state is kept in {ctx->iv}, treated as an 128 big-endian integer, counting the crypto blocks, starting from the IV given to the Init function.  This counter tells the number of the next crypto block to be encrypted/decrypted.  This works with random access, i.e. ctx->iv can be computed manually before an *Update call, if on crypto block boundary.  As soon as at least one byte is returned from a cipher op, the counter is updated to hold the next crypto block to be processed.  If byte-level random access is wanted, there is also {ctx->num} that holds the byte offset into the current crypto block.  For this to work, the block must have been started on, i.e. a cipher op where {ctx->num} was equal to zero must have been issued, in order to correctly setup the internal state.

Below is a stupid, but still working example of how CTR mode can be used for random access decryption.

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void add_be_128(uint8_t *ctr, ptrdiff_t delta) {
        for (int n = 15; delta != 0 && n >= 0; n--) {
                // The risk of overflow can safely be neglected.                
                ptrdiff_t nval = ctr[n] + delta;
                ctr[n] = nval & 0xff;
                delta = nval >> 8;
        }
}

int main() {
     uint8_t in[] =
          "0123456789abcdeffedcba9876543210fedcba98765432100123456789abcdef";
     uint8_t out[64];
     int sz;
     uint8_t cmp[33];
     uint8_t key[] = {
          0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0xc0, 0x01, 0xd0, 0x0d,
          0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef, 0xc0, 0x01, 0xd0, 0x0d
     };
     uint8_t iv[] = {
          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
     };

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
     EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
     EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, out, &sz, in, sizeof in);
     EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, out + sz, &sz);
     EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
     add_be_128(ctx->iv, 1);
     EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, cmp, &sz, out + 16, 32);
     EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, cmp + sz, &sz);
     cmp[32] = 0;
     printf("%s %d\n", cmp, strncmp(in + 16, cmp, 32));
     EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
     int new = ctx->num + 8;
     add_be_128(ctx->iv, (new - 1) / 16);
     ctx->num = 0;
     EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, cmp, &sz, out, 1);
     ctx->num = new;
     EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, cmp, &sz, out + 8, 32);
     EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, cmp + sz, &sz);
     cmp[32] = 0;
     printf("%s %d\n", cmp, strncmp(in + 8, cmp, 32));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution when I had to use the EVP openssl functions. Should work with every available cipher

```
/*! @file s70357.c
 * IS_Beleg by Markus Klemm
 * */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/*!
 * @param cipher_text Buffer, at least (plain_len + cipher_block_size - 1) bytes big,
 * where the encrypted data will be stored.
 * @param cipher_text_len Actual length of encrypted data in cipher_text in bytes
 */
bool mk_evp_encrypt(const unsigned char *plain_text,
                    const int plain_text_len,
                    unsigned char *cipher_text,
                    int *cipher_text_len,
                    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
                    unsigned char *key,
                    unsigned char *iv) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *context = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!context) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(context, cipher, NULL, key, iv)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }

    *cipher_text_len = 0;
    if (!EVP_EncryptUpdate(context, cipher_text, cipher_text_len, plain_text, plain_text_len)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }
    int final_block_len = 0;
    if (!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(context, cipher_text + *cipher_text_len, &final_block_len)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }
    *cipher_text_len += final_block_len;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
    return true;
}

/*! @param plain_text Buffer that must at least be cipher_text_len + cipher_block_size big
 * */
bool mk_evp_decrypt(const unsigned char *cipher_text,
                    const int cipher_text_len,
                    unsigned char *plain_text,
                    int *plain_text_len,
                    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
                    unsigned char *key,
                    unsigned char *iv) {
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *context = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!context) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(context, cipher, NULL, key, iv)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }

    *plain_text_len = 0;
    if (!EVP_DecryptUpdate(context, plain_text, plain_text_len, cipher_text, cipher_text_len)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }
    int final_block_size = 0;
    if (!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(context, plain_text + *plain_text_len, &final_block_size)) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
        return false;
    }
    *plain_text_len += final_block_size;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(context);
    return true;
}

struct file_memory_map_meta {
    int file_desc;
    struct stat file_info;
};

/*! @param digest Must be big engough to hold at least EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE
 * */
bool mk_evp_digest(const unsigned char *text,
                   const size_t text_len,
                   unsigned char *digest,
                   unsigned int *digest_len,
                   const EVP_MD *digest_type) {
    EVP_MD_CTX *context = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
    if (!context) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!EVP_DigestInit_ex(context, digest_type, NULL)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!EVP_DigestUpdate(context, text, text_len)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!EVP_DigestFinal_ex(context, digest, digest_len)) {
        return false;
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(context);

    return true;
}


void open_file_memory_mapped_read(char *file_path,
                                  void **file_memory,
                                  struct file_memory_map_meta *meta) {
    meta->file_desc = open(file_path, O_RDONLY);
    if (meta->file_desc == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open read file %s", file_path);
        perror(" ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (stat(file_path, &meta->file_info) != 0) {
        perror("Can't get source file infos");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void *source_mem = mmap(NULL, meta->file_info.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, meta->file_desc, 0);
    if (source_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Mapping read file failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *file_memory = source_mem;
}

void open_file_memory_mapped_write(char *file_path,
                                   void **file_memory,
                                   struct file_memory_map_meta *meta,
                                   size_t size) {
    meta->file_desc = open(file_path, O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 744);
    if (meta->file_desc == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open write file %s", file_path);
        perror(" ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (stat(file_path, &meta->file_info) != 0) {
        perror("Can't get source file infos");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void *source_mem = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, meta->file_desc, 0);
    if (source_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Mapping write file failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    *file_memory = source_mem;
}

void close_file_memory_mapped(void **file_memory, struct file_memory_map_meta *meta) {
    munmap(*file_memory, meta->file_info.st_size);
    close(meta->file_desc);
}

void create_key_iv_from_file(char *key_iv_path, unsigned char **key, unsigned char **iv, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher) {
    FILE *f = fopen(key_iv_path, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s", key_iv_path);
        perror(" ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *key = malloc(EVP_CIPHER_key_length(cipher));
    if (*key == NULL) {
        perror("Could not alloc for key");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher) != 0) {
        *iv = malloc(EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher));
        if (*iv == NULL) {
            perror("Could not alloc for iv");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } else {
        *iv = NULL;
    }
    if (fread(*key, 1, EVP_CIPHER_key_length(cipher), f) != EVP_CIPHER_key_length(cipher)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading key\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*iv != NULL) {
        if (fread(*iv, 1, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher), f) != EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(cipher)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading iv\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
}

unsigned char *permutate_key(unsigned char *key, unsigned corrupt_byte_pos) {
    key[corrupt_byte_pos] = key[corrupt_byte_pos] + 1; //although in DES, we could reduce to half because of parity bit

    return key;
}

bool is_pdf(unsigned char *data) {
    unsigned char pdf_start[] = {"%PDF"};
    unsigned char pdf_end[] = {"%%EOF"};

    return !memcmp(pdf_start, data, sizeof(pdf_start) - 1); //TODO check pdf_end, but cutaway the padding
}

void decrypt_mode(char *cipher_text_path,
                  char *plain_text_path,
                  char *key_iv,
                  unsigned corrupt_byte_pos,
                  char *cipher) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();//Needed for older versions to use EVP_get_cipherbyname
    const EVP_CIPHER *evp_cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname(cipher);
    EVP_cleanup(); //cleanup for OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms
    if (evp_cipher == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cipher %s not found\n", cipher);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    void *cipher_text_mem;
    struct file_memory_map_meta cipher_text_meta;
    open_file_memory_mapped_read(cipher_text_path,
                                 &cipher_text_mem, &cipher_text_meta);

    void *plain_text_mem;
    struct file_memory_map_meta plain_text_meta;
    open_file_memory_mapped_write(plain_text_path,
                                  &plain_text_mem, &plain_text_meta, cipher_text_meta.file_info.st_size);

    if (chmod(plain_text_path, cipher_text_meta.file_info.st_mode) != 0) {
        perror("Can't copy file permissions");
    }
    if (lseek(plain_text_meta.file_desc, cipher_text_meta.file_info.st_size - 1 + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(evp_cipher),
              SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("Can't seek to new end of destination file");
    }
    unsigned char dummy = 0;
    if (write(plain_text_meta.file_desc, &dummy, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Couldn't write dummy byte");
    }

    unsigned char *key;
    unsigned char *iv;
    create_key_iv_from_file(key_iv, &key, &iv, evp_cipher);


    //now lets try the keys
    const unsigned key_len = EVP_CIPHER_key_length(evp_cipher);
    int plain_len = 0;

    bool decrypt_return = mk_evp_decrypt(cipher_text_mem,
                                         cipher_text_meta.file_info.st_size, plain_text_mem, &plain_len, evp_cipher,
                                         key, iv);
    while (!decrypt_return || !is_pdf(plain_text_mem)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Key 0x");
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < key_len; ++i) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%02X", key[i]);
        }

        fprintf(stderr, " didn't catch it trying the next one\n");
        plain_len = 0;
        decrypt_return = mk_evp_decrypt(cipher_text_mem,
                                        cipher_text_meta.file_info.st_size, plain_text_mem, &plain_len, evp_cipher,
                                        permutate_key(key, corrupt_byte_pos), iv);
    }
    if (ftruncate(plain_text_meta.file_desc, plain_len) != 0) {
        perror("Trimming of final plain text failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    free(key);
    free(iv);
    close_file_memory_mapped(&plain_text_mem, &plain_text_meta);
    close_file_memory_mapped(&cipher_text_mem, &cipher_text_meta);
}

void hash_mode(char *text_path,
               char *opt_hash_path,
               char *digest_name) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();//Needed for older versions to use EVP_get_cipherbyname
    const EVP_MD *digest = EVP_get_digestbyname(digest_name);
    EVP_cleanup(); //cleanup for OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms
    if (digest == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Digest %s not found\n", digest_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void *text_mem;
    struct file_memory_map_meta text_meta;
    open_file_memory_mapped_read(text_path,
                                 &text_mem, &text_meta);


    unsigned char hash[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned hash_len = 0;
    mk_evp_digest(text_mem, text_meta.file_info.st_size, hash, &hash_len, digest);

    if (strlen(opt_hash_path) == 0) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < hash_len; ++i) {
            printf("%02X", hash[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        FILE *out_file = fopen(opt_hash_path, "wb");
        if (!out_file) {
            perror("Could not open output file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (fwrite(hash, hash_len, 1, out_file) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not write the hash correctly\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fclose(out_file);
    }

    close_file_memory_mapped(&text_mem, &text_meta);
}

void encrypt_mode(char *plain_text_path,
                  char *cipher_text_path,
                  char *key_iv,
                  char *cipher) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();//Needed for older versions to use EVP_get_cipherbyname
    const EVP_CIPHER *evp_cipher = EVP_get_cipherbyname(cipher);
    EVP_cleanup(); //cleanup for OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms
    if (evp_cipher == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cipher %s not found\n", cipher);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    void *plain_text_mem;
    struct file_memory_map_meta plain_text_meta;
    open_file_memory_mapped_read(plain_text_path,
                                 &plain_text_mem, &plain_text_meta);

    void *cipher_text_mem;
    struct file_memory_map_meta cipher_text_meta;
    open_file_memory_mapped_write(cipher_text_path,
                                  &cipher_text_mem, &cipher_text_meta, plain_text_meta.file_info.st_size);

    if (chmod(cipher_text_path, plain_text_meta.file_info.st_mode) != 0) {
        perror("Can't copy file permissions");
    }
    if (lseek(cipher_text_meta.file_desc, plain_text_meta.file_info.st_size + EVP_CIPHER_block_size(evp_cipher),
              SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("Can't seek to new end of destination file");
    }
    unsigned char dummy = 0;
    if (write(cipher_text_meta.file_desc, &dummy, 1) == -1) {
        perror("Couldn't write dummy byte");
    }

    unsigned char *key;
    unsigned char *iv;
    create_key_iv_from_file(key_iv, &key, &iv, evp_cipher);

    int cipher_text_len = 0;
    if (!mk_evp_encrypt(plain_text_mem, plain_text_meta.file_info.st_size, cipher_text_mem, &cipher_text_len,
                        evp_cipher, key, iv)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Encryption went wrong\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ftruncate(cipher_text_meta.file_desc, cipher_text_len) != 0) {
        perror("Trimming of final plain text failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(key);
    free(iv);
    close_file_memory_mapped(&plain_text_mem, &plain_text_meta);
    close_file_memory_mapped(&cipher_text_mem, &cipher_text_meta);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    enum mode {
        none, decrypt, encrypt, hash
    } mode = none;
    char in_path[512];
    memset(in_path, '\0', sizeof(in_path));
    char out_path[512];
    memset(out_path, '\0', sizeof(out_path));
    char key_path[512];
    memset(key_path, '\0', sizeof(key_path));
    char cipher[512];
    memset(cipher, '\0', sizeof(cipher));
    unsigned corrupt_byte_pos = -1;

    int flag;
    while ((flag = getopt(argc, argv, "deh i:o:c:k:b:")) != -1) {
        switch (flag) {
            case 'e':
                mode = encrypt;
                break;
            case 'd':
                mode = decrypt;
                break;
            case 'h':
                mode = hash;
                break;
            case 'i':
                strncpy(in_path, optarg, sizeof(in_path) - 1);
                break;
            case 'o':
                strncpy(out_path, optarg, sizeof(out_path) - 1);
                break;
            case 'k':
                strncpy(key_path, optarg, sizeof(key_path) - 1);
                break;
            case 'c':
                strncpy(cipher, optarg, sizeof(cipher) - 1);
                break;
            case 'b':
                errno = 0;
                corrupt_byte_pos = strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
                if (errno != 0) {
                    perror("Could not read byte position, assuming key is ok");
                    corrupt_byte_pos = -1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
                break;
        }
    }

    switch (mode) {
        case decrypt:
            decrypt_mode(in_path, out_path, key_path, corrupt_byte_pos, cipher);
            break;
        case encrypt:
            encrypt_mode(in_path, out_path, key_path, cipher);
            break;
        case hash:
            hash_mode(in_path, out_path, cipher);
            break;
        case none:
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "No mode was specified\n");
            printf("Usage %s -<MODE> -<PARAMETERS>\n", argv[0]);
            printf("\t<MODE>:\n");
            printf("\t\t e Encrypt aka Aufgabe 3\n");
            printf("\t\t d Decrypt aka Aufgabe 1\n");
            printf("\t\t h Hash aka Aufgabe 2\n");
            printf("\t<PARAMETERS>: \n");
            printf("\t\t i Input file path\n");
            printf("\t\t o Output file path, optional for hash mode\n");
            printf("\t\t k Key/IV file path, optional for hash mode\n");
            printf("\t\t c EVP Cipher/Digest to be used\n");
            printf("\t\t b Corrupt byte position, counted from 0, optional for hash mode\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```