# c++ open SSL EVP_aes_128_cbc()

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Can someone please give me an example of encryption and decryption using

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

in c++ code: Aes 128 with cbc a key and an iv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several answers on Stack Overflow, e.g. [AES CTR 256 Encryption Mode of operation on OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141860/aes-ctr-256-encryption-mode-of-operation-on-openssl)

If you don't know what [CBC and friends are all about](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2009/7/22/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing.html), I would suggest either reading up on it, or using a wrapper library.  OpenSSL is fairly low level, so if you don't know what you are doing, you will probably be not only more productive with a wrapper library, but also do things the *correct* way as well.

Comment: can you please wite a small code?:) I can't manage to give a good example. My key and iv are unsigned char and are fixed values.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/guanzhi/crypto-with-openssl. what is outlen and out? can u fill the example?