# Encryption task crashed using QT, Openssl what should i do?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting the following error when the function below runs on Qt Creator

> /home/zero/build-EncryptionTask2-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/EncryptionTask2 crashed.

I think it comes from converting to/from `QByteArray` data type

```
QByteArray encryotionProgress(QByteArray d_input)
{
//QByteArray d_output;
params->key = key;
params->iv  = iv;
/* Indicate that we want to encrypt */
   params->encrypt = 1;
/* Set the cipher type you want for encryption-decryption */
  params->cipher_type = EVP_aes_256_cbc();

 /* Encrypt the given file */
   unsigned char *enc_out;

   AES_set_encrypt_key( params->key, 256, &enc_key);
   AES_encrypt((unsigned char*)(d_input.data()), enc_out, &enc_key);
   QByteArray d_output((char*)enc_out);//convert back to qbyte array

  return d_output;
 }
```

Comment: Does `AES_encrypt` produce a null terminated string? If not how does `QByteArray` know the lenghth of the buffer?

Comment: Does AES_encrypt allocate memory for its output ? if it does, you should free it before returning from encryotionProgress to avoid memory leak, if it does not, you should allocate memory for output, before passing pointer to AES_encrypt

Comment: Is `params` defined? Add condition `if(!params) return;`, its a good practice. Did you use debug to look for possible place where error occured? In most of the cases it a segmentation fault due improper memory management.

Comment: @SumitJha: No, it's not goot practice. The code here is a snippet (unfortunately) but it's likely that `params!=nullptr` is a class invariant. In fact, `return` is downright wrong here. The return type isn't `void`.

Comment: Can you provide debugger messages ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory must be allocated to `enc_out` before passing to function `AES_encrypt`.

First, get the size of of output buffer:

```
const int n = sizeof(unsigned char) * ((d_input.length() + AES_BLOCK_SIZE) / AES_BLOCK_SIZE) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

Then allocate memory to `enc_out` using either of the following ways:

**C++ style dynamic memory allocation:**

```
unsigned char* enc_out = new unsigned char[n];
```

**C style dynamic memory allocation:**

```
unsigned char* enc_out = (unsigned char *) malloc (n);
```

**Note:** Do not forget to `free` or `delete[]`  memory allocated to `enc_out` after using  it.

**Stack memory allocation:**

```
unsigned char  enc_out[n];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Unless you are forced to use C, you should never use `malloc` with c++

Comment: yes, it solves the problem but after using `AES_encrypt` and `AES_decrypt` in another function i cannot get the original file again 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yn0idsWMD_x_ZxZIAVruWKx5Kjl_DMX7/view).

Comment: @HamdyFouad [How to do encryption using AES in Openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889492/how-to-do-encryption-using-aes-in-openssl)

Comment: i searched the internet and found an example, have not more info

Comment: @MohammadKanan  is there any other function to encrypt?