# Encrypt file Using AES

Tags: c, encryption, struct, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to build a program the takes in a file (an EXE of arbitrary size), encrypts its and copies it to a structure. Then decrypt it later and make sure it is the same for use.

I am having a hard time encrypting then decrypting the file. It seems to not be encrypting properly and I do not know how to test it.

Here are my questions:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is there a better library to encrypt using AES? or shall I stick with openSSL
3. Lets say I wanted to use another key say "HelloWorld". Can I just use that string and use it as an argument for the encryption algorithm? Do I have to set the correct bit length of the key? If so how?

Code:

```
struct structData{
    unsigned char * FileBuffer;
    unsigned long FileSize;
    //More stuff in here
};

struct Data sData;


/*
 I load the data here, and fill in the data etc
*/
unsigned char Key[]={ //128bit key
    0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77,
    0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff,
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
};

unsigned char *enc_data = malloc(sData->FileSize);//Temporary holder for the File

AES_KEY enc_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(Key,128,&enc_key);//Put key defined here
AES_encrypt(sData->FileBuffer,enc_data,&enc_key);
sData->FileBuffer = enc_data;//This should move the stuff over
//Should be encrypted here
sData->FileBuffer = enc_data;//Copy the output to the file buffer
free(enc_data);//Free memory

AES_KEY dec_key;
AES_set_decrypt_key(Key, 128,&dec_key);
AES_decrypt(sData->FileBuffer,dec_data,&dec_key);
sData->FileBuffer = dec_data;

free(dec_data);
```

Anything would help, hopefully I am heading in the right direction, my C skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: is this actually the code you are using? because you free(enc_data) and try to decrypt it afterwards. You should allocate an new chunk of memory for pFileBuffer and use memcpy() to copy the contents of enc_data. Note: sData->pFileBuffer = enc_data; does not copy anything it just sets pFileBuffer to point to the same location as enc_data.

Comment: it can't be the code he's using. There is no `pFileBuffer` member of that structure.

Comment: It is not the code I am useing, I renamed some of the variables, I will fix it in edit.

Comment: You do not need a temp buffer larger than the block size of the algorithm, which is 16 bytes (128 bits). The memory leak aside, this code will only encrypt **one** block (16 bytes). In short, you need to be more familiar with how block ciphers work. (Still trying to understand why you specified a 192-bit key, but you hard-hand-coded the length to 128, so its not really an issue).

Comment: @robin.koch Ah ok. This is what I was figuring, thanks! and WhozCraig, I see I incorrectly specified the Key length. So the proper way to do this is to loop this function until eof?

Comment: This may be a good starting point to deal with AES : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039066/aes-ctr128-encrypt-string-and-vice-versa-ansi-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Well, that's a bit too open ended to answer thoroughly.

Starting with the obvious, you are using low-level `AES_*` interfaces and operating AES in ECB mode. You are not deriving your key. And you are hard coding a key.

It also looks like you have memory management problems. You don't appear to use `FileSize` anywhere.

---

> Is there a better library to encrypt using AES?

*If* you are going to use OpenSSL, then you should probably use the `EVP_*` interfaces *and* use an authenticated encryption mode like GCM. With GCM mode, you get confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

---

> Lets say I wanted to use another key say "HelloWorld". Can I just use that string and use it as an argument for the encryption algorithm? Do I have to set the correct bit length of the key? If so how?

You should derive a key rather than use it directly from your passphrase. See [`EVP_BytesToKey(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) and [`PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html) in the OpenSSL docs (the OpenSSL wiki does not have an article or example code).

---

> ... shall I stick with OpenSSL

If you use the library correctly, then you should be happy with it.

Otherwise, you can use any other library you like. See the OpenSSL wiki's [Related Links](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Related_Links) page for some alternatives.

Comment: Don't you love the way you can create very extensive answers regarding crypto, just to be ignored by the person asking the question? I've voted up a few of your (not accepted) answers. Appreciate the OpenSSL related answers you've provided here!

Comment: @jww thanks for pointing me in the correct direction. I am sorry it took me so long to make your answer the correct answer but I was working on it and finally solved it using your advice (along with others). I have posted a solution using the EVP api over here: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856303/openssl-aes-256-cbc-via-evp-api-in-c This works on binary data, so an executable will also be encrypted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of AES encryption with Javascript.

The live platform is [here](http://encrypto.online/)

The AES code is located [here](http://encrypto.online/assets/js/aes.js)